# Which files to distribute using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, distutils, cx-freeze

I'm using cx_freeze to freeze a Python script for distribution to other windows systems. I did everything as instructed and cx_freeze generated a  `build\exe.win32-2.6` folder in the folder containing my sources. This directory now contains a a bunch of PYD files, a library.zip file, the python DLL file and the main executable. Which of these files would I need to distribute? Any help, guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need all of them.